# regex match single character plus exact string

Tags: regex

I have regex which match single letter like this `^[a-zA-Z]{1}$`

how to extend this to match not only single letter like a or b but also two additional strings like `0-9` and `All` ?

So the regext should match

```
a yes
b yes
ab not
1 not
12 not
1-9 yes
something no
all yes
alli no
```

Comment: What do you mean by "two additional strings"? Can you give examples of input and expected output?

Comment: Are the yes/no/not part of the string to be matched or are they the result of the match?

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?:[a-z]|\d+-\d+|all)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ybkodL/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start non-capture group

  - `[a-z]`: Match a letter `a-z`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\d+-\d+`: Match 2 digits separate with `-`
  - `|`: OR
  - `all`: Match `all`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End